# html form textarea formatting in different browsers

Tags: html, css

There is this form I have and I would like the description field to be a textarea with the text box having the blue div as its background. I can adjust the rows and columns but problem is in google chrome it works but firefox it adds 2 extra rows which prevents me from fitting the textarea in the div properly...Any idea on what I can do about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/MwnSn/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style textareas with css width and height:

```
.the-blue-background {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.the-blue-background textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MwnSn/14/

Comment: thank both of you guys for helping me out! I was stuck on this from sooo long!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than specifying `cols` and `rows`, use CSS to specify `height` and `width`

You are a lot more likely to get a cross-browser result with this method.